# Outdoor box or conduit body?

Tags: electrical, conduit, stucco

I have a flood light that's not properly mounted and I'd like to run conduit to raise it about two feet higher on a stucco and brick wall.

The wires exit the house via a small, approx. half inch hole ( *see photo* ). I was planning on using a service entrance LB [like this one](https://www.garvinindustries.com/fittings/aluminum-and-malleable-iron-conduit-bodies/aluminum-service-entrance-lb/slb125?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8Lj1_5fr6QIV4AiICR3PWA-nEAQYCiABEgLUjPD_BwE) or a regular [conduit body](https://www.google.com/search?q=conduit%20body&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi57eryl-vpAhUChXIEHaUFC4QQ_AUoAnoECA4QBA&biw=1614&bih=916&dpr=2#imgrc=6ZIIsJXv6L2dcM) but I just want to make sure this is the most appropriate way to handle wires exiting a house without conduit?

Is using a [weatherproof box](https://www.constructionprotips.com/jobsite-tips/electrical/working-with-pvc-conduit/) better than a conduit body in this case?  I think the box would be unnecessarily bulky compared to the conduit body/service entrance LB but what would be the best option to seal it from the weather?

[image: Wires exiting the house]

Comment: Can you access the other side of the wall?

Comment: You will have to change wire types to raise the fixture. You can recess a fixture in that location and still use NM but to come outside with a box or go up the wall  you need a box for a splice then wire rated for the location. 
Me I would just cut in a box and put the light there with the original wire that is code compliant.

Answer (score 3):

*cringe*

This was a bodge job from the beginning.  Hole unguarded, NM cable coming outside as if Shelter-in-place was over, fitting intended for octagon box misapplied to mount an outside light, etc.  Is the light even rated for outdoors??

(NM-B is not legal nor reliable outside; this could be tripping a GFCI if it was on it just from hot-ground leakage from insulation breakdown. Meanwhile the paper stuffing is wicking water tens of feet down the cable).

I think a plain old 1/2" conduit body would be perfectly fine as part of a nutritious breakfast - er, proper wiring method.

I would run up the wall with conduit to your desired light location then fit an appropriate box there.  My preference is a box where the flexible cable to the light exits the bottom of the box with a proper liquidtight strain relief; that way *when* the liquidtight leaks, water still doesn't get in.  You don't want the conduit to turn into a rain superhighway into your house.

The only issue is, you can't run NM cable outside, and UF cable won't fit inside conduit (unless you make it stupid-huge).  That limits you to THHN wire, which works great in conduit (use stranded since you'll be splicing to wire nuts at both ends).  You will need to make a transition from NM to THHN somewhere inside the house, and that requires an accessible junction box to do that.

Comment: thanks... so if I use the conduit body, is caulking enough to seal that hole in the stucco and the gap between the stucco and the conduit body?

Comment: you can't do junctions inside a conduit body

Comment: Yeah, I was envisioning to extend the conduit through the wall, to a junction box inside.  Make the NM to THHN transition there.  Can't do it in a conduit body unless the body is *absolutely gigantic* like junction-box size, and that... defeats the purpose...